# Сводная таблица php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Суть задачи элементарна: есть n одинаковых таблиц - пока их 83, но будет 24k. Мне нужно банально их просуммировать и результаты записать в сводную таблицу с такой же структурой.

Пока получилось следующее (работает только для одного показателя uid=2). Если делаю uid IN (2,4..n), то суммируется все в кучу... Мне же нужно получить массив данных

```
Array
(
    [uid_1] => Array
        (
            [all] => ..
            [go] => ...
        )
 [uid_n] => Array
        (
            [all] => ..
            [go] => ...
        )
)
```

Пока у меня следующее:

```
$sub_query='(';
FOR($i = 1; $i <=82; $i++){
    $sub_query.='SELECT `uid`, `all` as tot, `go` as tot2
    FROM 2012_r_'.$i.'_f1 where uid=2
    UNION ALL
    ';
}
    $sub_query.='SELECT `uid`, `all` as tot, `go` as tot2
    FROM 2012_r_83_f1 where uid=2
    ) AS Total 
    LEFT JOIN 2012_cfo_f1 ON Total.uid = 2012_cfo_f1.uid';

$query="SELECT 2012_cfo_f1.uid, SUM( tot ) as `all` , SUM( tot2 ) as `go` 
FROM ".$sub_query;
```

Структура таблицы следующая:

```
uid|all|go
```

Я просто уверен, что есть какое-то базовое решение. Буду признателен за совет!

P. S.

В общем хитро все оказалось... У меня таблицы в InnoDB, но если их перевести в MyISAM, то можно сделать merge... А потом уже из merge таблицы сделать выборку в финальную таблицу используя group by..

Получилось примерно следующее:

**1 итерация (все в кучу)**

```
CREATE TABLE myTotal (uid INT NOT NULL, go varchar(20), KEY(uid))
ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(2012_r_1_f1,2012_r_2_f1, ... ,2012_r_83_f1) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
```

**2 итерация...**

```
CREATE TABLE 2012_rf_f1 as select uid, sum(go) as go FROM `myTotal where 1 GROUP BY uid
```

Как-то так... Буду проверять, что будет, если в колонках текст.

Comment: Целиком средствами MySQL задача не решается?

Comment: @Sergiks уверен, что да, но как?....
p.s. а в чем у меня не средства mysql?
в цикле просто формируется запрос, перечисляя таблицы - тупо, но как иначе: буду признателен за содействие

Answer (score 3):

Сам спросил - сам ответил... Видимо было в синтаксисе дело:

```
$sub_query='(';
for($i = 1; $i <=82; $i++){
    $sub_query.='SELECT `pokazatel`, `uid`, `all` as tot, `go` as tot2 FROM 2012_r_'.$i.'_f1
    UNION ALL 
    ';
}
    $sub_query.='SELECT `pokazatel`,`uid`, `all` as tot, `go` as tot2 FROM 2012_r_83_f1) AS u  GROUP BY uid';
$query="SELECT pokazatel, uid,SUM(tot) as `all`, SUM(tot2) AS `go` FROM ".$sub_query;
```